# Loading indicator does not hide if api failed to retrieve data

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I want to show a loading indicator at the beginning of the first api call when list of items is being fetched from the server. Everything is okay if data is fetched successfully. That means the loading indicator got invisible if data loaded successfully. The code is given bellow.

must use this code in view model

```
    protected open fun <T> Single<T>.asPageLoadEventSource(eventId: Int = Random.nextInt()): Single<T> {
    var emitter: SingleEmitter<Any>? = null
    val single = Single.create<Any> { emitter = it }
    pageLoadEventSingles[eventId] = single
    return this.doOnSuccess { emitter?.onSuccess(it as Any) }
        .doOnError { emitter?.tryOnError(it) }
}
```

view model

```
    private fun getIncomingStiDest() {
    val queries = mapOf(
        "last_status" to stiDest,
        "type" to incoming
    )

    getStiDestActionLiveData.value = Resource(Status.LOADING)
    getDashboardCounterUseCase.execute(queries).asPageLoadEventSource().subscribe({
        getStiDestActionLiveData.value = Resource(Status.SUCCESS, it)
    }, {
        getStiDestActionLiveData.value = Resource(Status.ERROR, it)
    }).collect()
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code where  you have handled the success and error

Comment: Yes Please! Share more code it's not clear how you have handled UI according to event. Is tryOnError necessary why are you doing that immediately after getting error?

Comment: I have added the code can it help me